# Error on BigQuery load BQ command - Could not connect with BigQuery server due to: RedirectMissingLocation

Tags: google-bigquery

Getting an error while loading a parquet file (~525MB) using the BQ command from a local Ubuntu machine:
Could not connect with BigQuery server due to: RedirectMissingLocation

Other smaller files load perfectly on the same set up. The same file uploads perfectly on Windows, the issue is on Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws.

Some old posts suggest a possible size limit and downgrading the gcloud version.
Wondering if a better solution is available.

Thanks.